# Why Signalr does not stable all time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I am workign witha a signalr project using .Net framework 4.6. And I have a base controller:

```
public abstract class Base<THub> : ApiController where THub : IHub
{
    private static readonly Func<IHubContext> ValueFactory = () => GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<THub>();

    private readonly Lazy<IHubContext> hub = new Lazy<IHubContext>(ValueFactory);

    protected IHubContext Hub => hub.Value;
}
```

SO I am creating my Notification controller from Base.

```
public class NewsController : Base<NotificationHub>{
     public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateNews(string name){
        // connect database
        // create news on database
        ....

        Hub.Clients.All.send(name);     
     }
}
```

And I am connecting this hub from my desktop applicaiton. I am creating news using CreateNews(string name)action, this action sends notification at first few attempts.
And then it does not send a few attempts, and some times later again sends notification to client.

```
[HubName("notification")]
public class NotificationHub: Hub
{
    private static readonly ConnectionMapping<string> Connections = new ConnectionMapping<string>();

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

        Connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);

        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        var name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

        Connections.Remove(name, Context.ConnectionId);

        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }

    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        var name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

        if (!Connections.GetConnections(name).Contains(Context.ConnectionId))
        {
            Connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);
        }

        return base.OnReconnected();
    }
}
```

I set break points in my desktop client, there is no error or connection failures. It always works. But notifications does not send all time called CreateNews(string name)action.

What are the possible causes?

Comment: you are trying to use your hub class object in your controller, right?

Comment: yes exactly, when a news created, controller will send notification to all clients. is there any other way?

Comment: no, as per my knowledge you can not use hub class in controller. because all the active connection is persist in Hub class, so when you try to use it in your controller it will create new instance of it.

Comment: hmm ok what can I do?

Comment: i am updating answer, it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your desktop application start, you need to add that connectionid in your hub class object. so you need to implement your signalR object in desktop app as well.

so now when you create news from the desktop app, it will call hub class directly where you will get all active connections, where you want to send notification.

so you need to implement signalR Both side.

Comment: I am not creating news from desktop app. I am creating news from web applicaiton. Desktop application is seperately installed computers to notify users to show alerts when a news created..

Comment: ok, but for it you need to use signalR from both side, so when you click on create post, first you need to call hub class from web application using javascript. hope you know how to call hub class method from javascript.